# Is init process a daemon process

Tags: process, daemon, init

I want to know whether init process is a daemon process?

Thanks,
LinuxPenseur

Comment: Daemon as in it runs in the background? Yes it is. It's the mother of all processes on Unix & Linux systems (AFAIK).

Answer (score 4):

`init` is the mother of all processes and can be thought of as a `daemon`.

One big difference however is that while daemons run in the background and can be stopped and restarted, killing init will kill the os.

Comment: Is it possible to kill init process? Not by halt or shutdown or the like.. I want to kill it without killing other processes. Is that possible?